# ASP.NET Grid with CSS in Rows and Columns

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code

```
List<Department> depts = new List<Department>();

Department.Add(new Department() { DNo = 1, DName = "Accounting", DFloor="6" });
Department.Add(new Department() { DNo = 2, DName = "FInance", DFloor="3" });
```

I want to bind this data to a GridView, so that it outputs the following. Observe the classes on each th and tr. How can I achieve this in ASP.NET?

```
<thead>
<tr>
 <th class="DNo">DNo</th>
 <th class="DName">DName</th>
 <th class= "DFloor">DFloor</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
 <td class="DNo">1</td>
 <td class="DName">Accounting</td>
 <td class="DFloor">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="DNo">2</td>
 <td class="DName">FInance</td>
 <td class="DFloor">3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're creating your columns, use the `HeaderStyle-CssClass` and `ItemStyle-CssClass` attributes.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="DNo" ItemStyle-CssClass="DNo" DataField="DNo" HeaderText="DNo" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="DName" ItemStyle-CssClass="DName" DataField="DName" HeaderText="DName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-CssClass="DFloor" ItemStyle-CssClass="DFloor" DataField="DFloor" HeaderText="DFloor" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in your code behind (`Page_Load` event handler works), bind your data to the grid:

```
gv.DataSource = depts;
gv.DataBind();
```

Usually, people will wrap that in an `if (!IsPostBack) { }` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `GridView class`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DNo" DataField="DNo" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DName" DataField="DName" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DFloor" DataField="DFloor" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
GridView1.DataSource = depts;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the columns autogenerated or not? Because if they are, you need to change it to `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and set the `CssClass` properties for both, `Header` and `Item`